# manage a extjs tbar disable/enable from other tbar

Tags: extjs

can i manage a extjs tbar disable/enable from other tbar?

Thanks for your answer. I got solution, something like this:

> ```
> tbar:[{ id:'tambahid',
>  disabled:true,
>       },
>       { text: 'Toggle' + (local ? 'Off' : 'On'),
>  enableToggle: true,
>  toggleHandler:
>  function(){
>  var hidd = Ext.getCmp('tambahid');
>      if (this.pressed){Ext.Msg.alert(' ','Tambah Data Off');
>         hidd.enable();
>            }
> ```
>
> else {Ext.Msg.alert(' ','Tambah Data On');
>       hidd.disable();
>           }
>          }

But Im sure more efficient and clear code out there.

Answer (score 2):

```
// ...
tbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
    id: 'mytb',
    items: [/* your tbar items */]
})
// ...

Ext.getCmp('mytb').disable();
```

Comment: Ext.getCmp is your best frand

Comment: Some lively discussion re: Ext.getCmp over here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?103569-Ext.getCmp-and-developers-using-it-as-a-crutch

Answer (score 0):

You could use a message bus to pass messages between decoupled components but that's probably overkill for this scenario.. Assuming both your toolbars belong to the same parent component, then the parent would take responsibility for enabling/disabling the other toolbar based on some action on the first toolbar. See this example here for an idea of where to start: http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=compcomm